nx jest pass args from cmd to test-setup.ts
I setup jest tests in my nx monorepo. I want to run my tests twice with different configurations and therefore want to use two different .env files.
I load my env in test-setup.ts:
dotenv.config({ path: 'apps/projectname/e2e/support/.env' });

My idea was to pass the env filename in args like so:
npx nx run projectname:e2e --envfile=myfilename

Unfortunately I couln´t find a way to read those args in test-setup.ts. In the process variable theres no mentioning of my envfile argument.
Is there another way to achieve this?

you can create separate jest config with its own test-setup.ts and use different path to your .env file. However it looks non optimal but if you can't find optimal solution maybe this workaround can help
